# Linq query simplification/encapsulation

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a database that contains records of all stores and their open and close times. Currently, I have a linq query to extract these times for each store in the database. Below is the code:

```
StoresDatabaseDataContext db = new StoresDatabaseDataContext();
var serverData = from c in db.Stores
                    where c.storeID == currentStore.id
                    select new
                    {
                        openTime = c.SundayOpen,
                        closeTime = c.SundayOpen < c.SundayClose ? c.SundayClose : c.MondayClose,
                        timeZone = c.TimeZone,
                        hasDaylightSavings = c.DaylightSavings
                    };

switch (weekDay)
{
    case DayOfWeek.Monday:
        serverData= from c in db.Stores
                        where c.storeID == currentStore.id
                        select new
                        {
                            openTime = c.MondayOpen,
                            closeTime = c.MondayOpen < c.MondayClose ? c.MondayClose : c.TuesdayClose,
                            timeZone = c.TimeZone,
                            hasDaylightSavings = c.DaylightSavings
                        };
        break;
    case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
        serverData = from c in db.Stores
                        where c.storeID == currentStore.id
                        select new
                        {
                            openTime = c.TuesdayOpen,
                            closeTime = c.TuesdayOpen < c.TuesdayClose ? c.TuesdayClose : c.WednesdayClose,
                            timeZone = c.TimeZone,
                            hasDaylightSavings = c.DaylightSavings
                        };
        break;
//...
}
```

This runs correctly, however there is a lot of duplicated code, and I would like to reduce this either through encapsulation or some other methodology. One simple approach would be to reduce the complexity of the switch statement:

```
serverData =    from c in db.Accounts
                where c.storeID == currentStore.id
                select new
                {
                    switch (weekDay)
                    {
                        case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                            openTime = c.MondayOpen;
                            closeTime = c.MondayOpen < c.MondayClose ? c.MondayClose : c.TuesdayClose;
                            break;
                        case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                            openTime = c.TuesdayOpen;
                            closeTime = c.TuesdayOpen < c.TuesdayClose ? c.TuesdayClose : c.WednesdayClose; 
                            break;
                        //....
                    },
                    timeZone = c.TimeZone,
                    hasDaylightSavings = c.DaylightSavings
                };
```

But I'm not sure how cleanly extract the times this way. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to delegate the creation of what is returned by the query into a helper factory class. Then you call the class when projecting the results from the query.

In the factory class, you could use delegates in order to simplify the calling to the getters (that vary according the DayOfWeek):

```
static class RecordFactory
{
    private delegate DateTime TimeGetterFunction(Store s);

    static object New(Store store, DayOfWeek weekDay)
    {
        var timeOpen = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, TimeGetterFunction>();
        timeOpen.Add(DayOfWeek.Monday, (s) => s.mondayOpen);
        timeOpen.Add(DayOfWeek.Tuesday, (s) => s.tuesdayOpen);

        var timeClose = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, TimeGetterFunction>();
        timeClose.Add(DayOfWeek.Monday, (s) => s.mondayClose);
        timeClose.Add(DayOfWeek.Tuesday, (s) => s.tuesdayClose);

        return new { 
            TimeOpen = timeOpen[weekDay](store), 
            TimeClose = timeClose[weekDay](store) 
            //Add more properties...
        };
    }
}

// in your Linq query...
select RecordFactory.New(DayOfWeek.Monday, s);
```